# C instruction address

Tags: c, memory

Disclaimer, I not do anything in particular with regards this question, just curious.

Is it possible to take address of instruction or block in C?  in essence, is there jump equivalent in C?

for example:

```
void function() {
    int k;
    { // is a possible to go to this address from arbitrary point in code?
      int i, j;
      k += j+i;
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: @James no, I just read about closures and thought (only as exercise) if one can do it in C. so no particular platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest you can come using standard techniques is [setjmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setjmp) and [longjump](http://linux.die.net/man/3/longjmp). They won't get you access to the actual address though, because the `jmp_buf` object is opaque.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `goto`:

```
void function() {
    int k;
    { // is a possible to go to this address from arbitrary point in code?
myLabel:
      int i, j;
      k += j+i;
    }

// stuff

    goto myLabel;
}
```

Comment: but go to is scoped? Or is it not?

Comment: Goto isn't taking the address. Perhaps you were thinking of labels as values, a GCC extension? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

Comment: "arbitrary point in code" - I didn't realize you meant from literally *anywhere* in your program. Yeah, goto is just for within the function. For anyplace in code, yeah, setjmp/longjump is your man.